# How to use GSettings in my own gtk program

Tags: gtk

I'm writing a gtk program and I try to take advantage of GSetings to store my own program settings. But the program  failed at the statement "GSettings *settings = g_settings_new(SCHEMA);", with a message from the termial which said "Settings schema '*.*' is not installed". Must I install a settings schema before I create a GSettings object? If do, how to do that? If not, what should I do to store my settings? Is there a better way than using GSettings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guessed right; you have to install the schema before it will work. This is annoying because you can't run your program from your development directory without installing it anymore. Fortunately, it's easy to do right if you use Autotools:

In `configure.ac`, include the line

```
GLIB_GSETTINGS
```

and then put this in `Makefile.am`:

```
gsettings_SCHEMAS = org.my-domain.gschema.xml
@GSETTINGS_RULES@
```

where `org.my-domain` is a reverse domain name, used to identify your schema.

Comment: I did as what you said. Besides, I added the path of xml file to EXTRA_DIST, but the error still occured! I notice that the compiler has found the xml file and it could recognize the syntax error in xml.

Comment: Did you make sure that your variable `SCHEMA` contains the correct schema name?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure. My SCHEMA is something like "org.my-domain". Even if I    got the incorrent name, I could have created a new schema. But when I execute the command "gsettings list-schemas", I couldn't find any schema whose name is similar to my schema's.